# \newgeometry does not apply the right margins

Tags: header-footer, margins, geometry, scrlayer-scrpage, footer

I developed the following code for my document:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage[headsepline,footsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{graphicx,xcolor}
\usepackage[margin=38mm,includeheadfoot,head=32pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace, fontspec, hyperref, lastpage}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\onehalfspacing
\frenchspacing
\renewcommand{\headfont}{\normalfont}

\DeclareNewLayer[
    background,
    topmargin,
    mode=picture,
  contents={\includegraphics[height=\layerheight,width=\layerwidth]{Picture}}
]{top}

\DeclareNewLayer[
  background,
  bottommargin,
  mode=picture,
  contents={\includegraphics[height=\layerheight,width=\layerwidth]{Picture}}
]{bottom}

\DeclarePageStyleByLayers{Titlepage}{top,bottom}

\newpairofpagestyles[scrheadings]{Tableofcontents}
{
    \clearpairofpagestyles
    \ihead{Lorem ipsum}
    \chead{Lorem ipsum}
    \ohead{Lorem ipsum}
}

\newpairofpagestyles[scrheadings]{Content}
{
    \clearpairofpagestyles
    \ihead{Lorem ipsum}
    \chead{Lorem ipsum}
    \ohead{Lorem ipsum}
    \cfoot{\pagemark}
}
\renewcommand*{\pagemark}{{\usekomafont{pagenumber}Page~\thepage}}

\newcommand*{\Content}{
  \cleardoublepage
  \pagenumbering{arabic}
  \pagestyle{Content}
}

\makeglossaries

\begin{document}
    \pagenumbering{roman}
    \KOMAoption{headsepline}{false}
    \KOMAoption{footsepline}{false}
    Titlepage
    \newpage
    \newgeometry{left=2.5cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm}
    \setlength{\headsep}{10pt}
    
    \KOMAoption{headsepline}{true}
    \KOMAoption{footsepline}{true}
    \Content
    Lorem ipsum

    \printglossary[type=\acronymtype]
    \printglossary
\end{document}
```

Now I printed the document and the document margins don't have the size, that I have defined in '\newgeometry'.
Instead of: left=2.5cm, right=2cm, top=2cm, bottom=2cm the real margins on the paper are: left=2.8cm, right=2.3cm, top=1.4cm, bottom=2.6cm.
So somehow the margins are definitely not correct.
I'm happy about every suggestion to solve this problem.

**EDIT:**
Please compile with the XeLaTeX-Compiler.

Comment: please supply a test file that people can run to debug your problem. No one can run the code as posted.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thank you for the reply. I changed my code, so that everybody can run it.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the issue was with `\setlength{\headsep}{10pt}`. Check out the margins now.

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage[headsepline,footsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{graphicx,xcolor}
\usepackage[margin=38mm,includeheadfoot,
head=32pt,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace, fontspec, hyperref, lastpage}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\onehalfspacing
\frenchspacing
\renewcommand{\headfont}{\normalfont}

\DeclareNewLayer[
    background,
    topmargin,
    mode=picture,
  contents={\includegraphics[height=\layerheight,width=\layerwidth]{Picture}}
]{top}

\DeclareNewLayer[
  background,
  bottommargin,
  mode=picture,
  contents={\includegraphics[height=\layerheight,width=\layerwidth]{Picture}}
]{bottom}

\DeclarePageStyleByLayers{Titlepage}{top,bottom}

\newpairofpagestyles[scrheadings]{Tableofcontents}
{
    \clearpairofpagestyles
    \ihead{Lorem ipsum}
    \chead{Lorem ipsum}
    \ohead{Lorem ipsum}
}

\newpairofpagestyles[scrheadings]{Content}
{
    \clearpairofpagestyles
    \ihead{Lorem ipsum}
    \chead{Lorem ipsum}
    \ohead{Lorem ipsum}
    \cfoot{\pagemark}
}
\renewcommand*{\pagemark}{{\usekomafont{pagenumber}Page~\thepage}}

\newcommand*{\Content}{
  \cleardoublepage
  \pagenumbering{arabic}
  \pagestyle{Content}
}

\makeglossaries

\DeclareNewLayer[
  background,
  %outermargin,
  %topmargin,
  contents=\layercontentsmeasure
]{measurelayer}



\AddLayersToPageStyle{@everystyle@}{measurelayer}

\begin{document}
 %   \pagenumbering{roman}
  %  \KOMAoption{headsepline}{false}
   % \KOMAoption{footsepline}{false}
%    Titlepage
 %   \newpage
\newgeometry{left=2.5cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm}
%\setlength{\headsep}{10pt}
       % \setlength{\headheight}{1.5cm}
    
    \KOMAoption{headsepline}{true}
    \KOMAoption{footsepline}{true}
    \Content
    Lorem ipsum\footnote{asdf}

    \printglossary[type=\acronymtype]
    \printglossary
\end{document}
```